# Remote Subversion URL Completion in Bash

Tags: bash, svn, remote, autocomplete, url

Has anybody added Bash completion support for remote urls in svn commands? It could typically be implemented through parsing of calls to `svn ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache provides a script that gives bash completion when the script is sourced in your .bashrc - it uses  ~/.subversion/auth to provide the list for completion - it might be what you're looking for:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/client-side/bash_completion